# Will you appreciate my arguments against solipsism?

Tags: reality, idealism, solipsism

A month ago I wrote here. As time passed, I was able to collect some interesting arguments against solipsism in my piggy bank. Let's discuss them!

1. There is definitely me here. I can't exist alone by myself — then it would turn out that I invented this world, but how? After all, I don't know much about him, and in general I couldn't come up with existence as such — for this it is important to already be, and prerequisites are needed for being.
2. It follows from this that my mind is placed in this reality and is actually its product, since I have been brought up by my family all my life, received socialization at school and thus got acquainted with the world incomprehensible to me. Ie, my mind is not outside the context of reality. Does the outside world exist without me — this is an interesting question, but an even more interesting question is whether I exist without the outside world?
3. If I cannot influence the surrounding objects with the power of thought, then there is something objective on the other side of me that determines my reality. Which proves objective reality as such.
4. If reality is subjective, why does it mow under objective? Why are there more people, the laws of nature? Why should the idea of the objective be embodied in the subjective? So there is an "objective" if we can define it?
5. If this is so, then nothing prevents us from applying exactly the same train of thought to the revealed "real world" and in the same way declare it another Matrix that has an external "even more real" world, and so on ad infinitum.
6. Therefore, I can also define the "illusion". But the sleeper does not realize that he is asleep. In addition, in a dream, all his experiences are a projection of the inner world, and reality is based on facts that it is impossible to know everything, and that exist regardless of human thought.
7. I see a leaf. Is this an illusion? Okay, where did this green color come from? Green may not exist, but there is a definition for it. The fact that the leaf is green is obvious. Is this definition objective? How do I have a real idea of unreal things in my mind?
8. There is definitely me here. How is the real consciousness located in an unreal reality? Naturally, I conclude that if I am real, then everything else is too
9. I feel only my body, and I just walk around the world. I am not the ground I walk on. My feelings hint at the existence of reality, even if they are subjective. My feelings are contact with the outside world, without the outside world there would be no feelings either.
10. The concept of objective reality is more logical than the concept of fantasy inside my head. For being itself, an idea is not necessarily needed, but for an illusory existence, a reason is needed, "it still needs to be thought of." In order for an illusion to exist, it needs to be somewhere. At least something objective must exist. "A brain in a flask" is also a fictional concept, in fact, it exists only in this world and shows only a person's dependence on personal experience, nothing more.
11. As soon as a solipsist gives any definition of his "I", it can be immediately broken by simply mirroring the definition by the method of negation. If we know what "I" is, then we automatically know what "I" is not. So conceptually, the "I" already includes not everything that contradicts the original belief
12. Does it even make sense to separate objective reality and subjective reality? These are purely human concepts, because in fact there is only 1 large existence. Of course, this does not mean that it is real, but without the help of a person, being can only be simplified itself, so simplified itself is exactly the real physical.
13. Solipsism cannot be refuted, but it can be weakened. Just with the help of the theory of real reality, studying the current world, we can give ideas about it that sound more logical than solipsism.

Comment: 1st premise includes "I can't exist alone by myself ". Thus, solipsism is already rule out by it.

Comment: It might seem like you don't know "much" about the world, but you know everything you know, and for everything you don't know, none of that needs to exist at all. You might not know what your friend gets up to while you're not there, beyond what they tell you, but if they only exist in your mind, your thoughts of your interaction with them is the only existence they may have. That's what a solipsist might argue, at least.